# Json formatting trouble, when updating or editing my json file

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out why my json file is getting ekstra brackets.

this is my products.json file. Which has 2 too many brackets on the right end.

```
{"products": {"27": {"price": 5, "pk": 27, "name": "gfasd", "amount": 3, "type": "sokker", "imageURL": "/media/gg_6A1aZ75.jpg"}}}}}
```

I use a post_save function to update the json file whenever my model instance is geting saved.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=item, dispatch_uid="update_json")
def update_stock(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pk = str(instance.pk)
    with open(MEDIA_ROOT + '/json/products.json', 'r+') as json_file:
        products = json.loads(json_file.read()) 
        print(products) <--- 1
        products["products"].pop(pk, None)
        print(products) <--- 2
        products["products"][pk] = instance.returnAsJSON()
        print(products) <--- 3
        json_file.seek(0)
        json_file.write(json.dumps(products))
```

The print outs is:

```
{'products': {'27': {'price': 123, 'type': 'sokker', 'name': 'gfasd', 'amount': 3, 'pk': 27, 'imageURL': '/media/gg_6A1aZ75.jpg'}}}
{'products': {}}
{'products': {'27': {'price': 5, 'pk': 27, 'name': 'gfasd', 'amount': 3, 'type': 'sokker', 'imageURL': '/media/gg_6A1aZ75.jpg'}}}
```

The last print does not have the 2 ekstra brackets, so I'm guessing it may be the last two lines of my function. But I do not really know why they do it.

Comment: maybe you overwrite text in existing file and it doesn't remove previous text and you see old brackets - better open only to read `r` and later open only to write `w`.

Comment: Do not forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your issue*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably related with the way you are saving your files. You should add a `json_file.truncate()` after the `json_file.seek(0)`, so it will clean the file contents before saving anything new.

--

When you seek the 0 position, you just change the cursor, but the content of the file will still be the same, so if there was something bigger on the file, it will stay there.
Example:

products.json

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

.

```
with open("products.json", "r+") as json_file:
    json_file.seek(0)
    json_file.write(json.dumps({"foo":"b"})) # Will write {"foo":"b"} to the file
```

instead of resulting a file with `{"foo":"b"}`, the products.json file content will be `{"foo":"b"}"}`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It appears you are intending to read in the file, update the contents, then replace the file contents with the updated structure. Given that, I've made two more suggested changes to your code below, explicitly opening the file, reading in the data, closing the file, then at the end opening the file for writing, putting the new structure into it, and closing the file. This should ensure the file itself is clean each time.

---

You might consider that:

```
    products["products"][pk] = instance.returnAsJSON()
```

may be adding extraneous brackets as part of the JSON return.

Also, rather than use:

```
    products = json.loads(json_file.read()) 
    json_file.write(json.dumps(products))
```

Try using:

```
    products = json.load(json_file)
    json.dump(products, json_file)
```

As in:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=item, dispatch_uid="update_json")
def update_stock(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pk = str(instance.pk)
    with open(MEDIA_ROOT + '/json/products.json', 'r') as json_input_file:
        products = json.load(json_file); json_input_file.closed
    print(products) <--- 1
    products["products"].pop(pk, None)
    print(products) <--- 2
    products["products"][pk] = instance.returnAsJSON()
    print(products) <--- 3
    with open(MEDIA_ROOT + '/json/products.json', 'w') as json_output_file:
        json.dump(products, json_output_file); json_output_file.closed
```

Note I've also removed the:

```
         json_file.seek(0)
```

As I don't see the need here. If it turns out my tired eyes are missing something, please ignore, and perhaps let me know.

You may find these clean things up a little.